# Cómo hacer un quiebre de página (salto de pagina) en una exportación a impresión, html o pdf

Tags: html, .net, pdf

Estoy generando un reporte que es bastante largo incluyendo Texto, Imágenes y Grillas (Tablas); queda bien, pero al momento de exportarlo a PDF o hacer vista previa e impresión, el mismo formato corta al reporte y no deja ver claramente la información correctamente.

Por lo que deseo saber como hacer que un titulo o  o control no sea cortado y fuerce un Salto de Página y que no se corten las secciones.

Algún código de  o .Net para q fuerce ese salto??

[image: Asi lo genera]

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te sugerimos agregar lo que trataste o investigaste a tu pregunta, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Me uno al pedido para que puedas completar la pregunta con algo de codigo que estas utilizando par generar el PDF. Incluso que componentes estas utilizando. Para poder ayudarte mejor.